# SQL Can you use CASE in a WHERE in a nested SELECT?

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to get certain records into a subset for a 2nd query. The error I keep getting is : "Table alias used multiple times: Eqanswer -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 199 (line: 3 column: 22)" This was just the last message, I'm missing the obvious answer to solving it, but I really want to know if this will work.

```
    SELECT 
        e.entityid, e.entitynum, e.entityrole, eq.memotext, eq.fieldnum
    FROM 
        ( SELECT 
            DISTINCT entitynum 
          FROM Eqanswer, entities
                LEFT JOIN Eqanswer 
                    ON (Eqanswer.entitynum = entities.entitynum) 
          WHERE 
                entities.partyID LIKE
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (entities.partyID LIKE '%Joe%' 
                            OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bob%' 
                            OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bill%') 
                        THEN
                            (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
                            AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext, sql_date)=curDate() -5 ))
                        ELSE
                            (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
                            AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext,sql_date) = CurDate() -1 ))
                        END  
        ) AS bs  

        LEFT JOIN Entities e ON (bs.entitynum = e.entitynum)
        LEFT JOIN Eqanswer eq ON (bs.entitynum = eq.entitynum)
    WHERE((eq.entityrole = 'R_CKLIST' AND eq.fieldnum in (8,9,10,11,34,35))
    OR (eq.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eq.fieldnum in (104,112,158,160))
    OR (eq.entityrole = 'C_REVIEW' AND eq.fieldnum = 69))
    ORDER BY e.entitynum
```

I have tried both of the following:

```
    SELECT 
    e.entityid, e.entitynum, e.entityrole, eq.memotext, eq.fieldnum
    FROM ( SELECT 
        DISTINCT entitynum 
            FROM Eqanswer, entities
            LEFT JOIN Eqanswer 
                ON (Eqanswer.entitynum = entities.entitynum) 
      WHERE 
            entities.partyID 
                CASE 
                    WHEN (entities.partyID LIKE '%Joe%' 
                        OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bob%' 
                        OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bill%') 
                    THEN
                        (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
                        AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160
                        AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext, sql_date)=curDate() -5 ))
                    ELSE
                        (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
                        AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext,sql_date) = CurDate() -1 ))
                    END  
    ) AS bs  

    LEFT JOIN Entities e ON (bs.entitynum = e.entitynum)
    LEFT JOIN Eqanswer eq ON (bs.entitynum = eq.entitynum)
    WHERE((eq.entityrole = 'R_CKLIST' AND eq.fieldnum in (8,9,10,11,34,35))
    OR (eq.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eq.fieldnum in (104,112,158,160))
    OR (eq.entityrole = 'C_REVIEW' AND eq.fieldnum = 69))
    ORDER BY e.entitynum
```

and

```
    SELECT e.entityid, e.entitynum, e.entityrole, e.thestatus, eq.memotext, eq.dateentered, eq.datechgd, eq.fieldnum, e.docloc 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT eqanswer.entitynum FROM eqanswer
      LEFT JOIN entities ON (Eqanswer.entitynum = entities.entitynum) 
      WHERE entities.partyID
          CASE WHEN (entities.party3ID LIKE '%Joe%' 
                    OR entities.party3ID LIKE '%Bob%' 
                    OR entities.party3ID LIKE '%Bill%') 
                    THEN
          CASE WHEN  (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
             AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
             AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext, sql_date)=curDate() -5 ))
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ELSE
          CASE WHEN (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
             AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
             AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext,sql_date) = CurDate() -1 ))
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          END = 1
      ) AS bs  
   LEFT JOIN Entities e ON (bs.entitynum = e.entitynum)
   LEFT JOIN Eqanswer eq ON (bs.entitynum = eq.entitynum)
   WHERE((eq.entityrole = 'R_CKLIST' AND eq.fieldnum in (8,9,10,11,34,35))
   OR (eq.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eq.fieldnum in (104,112,158,160))
   OR (eq.entityrole = 'C_REVIEW' AND eq.fieldnum = 69))
   ORDER BY e.entitynum
```

Both are throwing errors, but that is like a syntax error (my fault).

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* and returns a scalar *value*. It can't return predicates (nor boolean values, assuming SQL Server, since there's no boolean *type*)

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL to query an Advantage DB from .Net, no Express, tSQL or server. Just the language to query the DB.

Answer (score 5):

You *really* have `Eqanswer` twice:

```
FROM Eqanswer, entities
LEFT JOIN Eqanswer
```

**Edit**

OK, this subselect is so wrong in so many places: (I'll add my comments as strings, rather than comments, to make them more prominent)

```
SELECT  entitynum 
FROM Eqanswer, entities
LEFT JOIN Eqanswer             'this is the duplicate table name'
    ON (Eqanswer.entitynum = entities.entitynum) 
WHERE entities.partyID LIKE    
    'LIKE implies that partyID AND the CASE expression are both strings'
    CASE 
        WHEN (entities.partyID LIKE '%Joe%' 
                        OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bob%' 
                        OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bill%') 
        THEN (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
             AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext, sql_date)=curDate() -5 ))
             'but THIS is a boolean expression'
        ELSE (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
             AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
             AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext,sql_date) = CurDate() -1 ))
             'and THIS too'
    END  
) AS bs
```

So the LIKE operates on a column with unknown data type, and a CASE resulting in a boolean expression. Most likely, the line `entities.partyID LIKE` is just a copy&paste error (hopefully). Let's just ignore it.

You cannot return a boolean expression as a result of the CASE clause. Therefore you need to rewrite the CASE to return an integer, and compare this value to match your intended WHERE condition.

Probably something like this:

```
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN (entities.partyID LIKE '%Joe%' 
                        OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bob%' 
                        OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bill%') 
        THEN
            CASE WHEN  (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
                 AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext, sql_date)=curDate() -5 ))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
                 AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
                 AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext,sql_date) = CurDate() -1 ))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END = 1
```

Comment: Fixed the multiple Eqanswer, but it doesn't like the "LIKE" statement after the WHERE clause.

Comment: Don't I need the field being used in the CASE (entities.partyID) after the WHERE?

Comment: When I try the following, I don't get any errors on the code check, but I still haven't got it to run.

Comment: CASE 1 as the lead in the CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        e.entityid, e.entitynum, e.entityrole, eq.memotext, eq.fieldnum
    FROM 
        ( SELECT 
            DISTINCT entitynum 
         /* THIS NEEDS TO BE CHANGED {Eqanswer} used 2 times without any alias */
          FROM Eqanswer, entities
                LEFT JOIN Eqanswer 
                    ON (Eqanswer.entitynum = entities.entitynum) 
          WHERE 
                entities.partyID LIKE  /* why you need this ?? */
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (entities.partyID LIKE '%Joe%' 
                            OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bob%' 
                            OR entities.partyID LIKE '%Bill%') 
                        THEN
                            (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' 
                            AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext, sql_date)=curDate() -5 ))
                        ELSE
                            (eqanswer.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eqanswer.fieldnum = 160 
                            AND (CONVERT(eqanswer.memotext,sql_date) = CurDate() -1 ))
                        END  
        ) AS bs  

        LEFT JOIN Entities e ON (bs.entitynum = e.entitynum)
        LEFT JOIN Eqanswer eq ON (bs.entitynum = eq.entitynum)
    WHERE((eq.entityrole = 'R_CKLIST' AND eq.fieldnum in (8,9,10,11,34,35))
    OR (eq.entityrole = 'F_TL' AND eq.fieldnum in (104,112,158,160))
    OR (eq.entityrole = 'C_REVIEW' AND eq.fieldnum = 69))
    ORDER BY e.entitynum
```

Comment: I like the code, but it throws the following error: "Invalid operand for operator: LIKE -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 279 (line:5 column: 26)"

Comment: remove like , i think you do not need it

Comment: Still doesn't like the CASE. Giving an error around the CASE statement.

Comment: The error: "Expected lexical element not found: ) There was a problem parsing the table names after the FROM keyword in your SELECT statement. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 279 (line: 5 column: 10)"

Comment: Ok , i have created a SQL fiddle example for you - [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a200f/6/0)